# Cordova 3.5 iOS - Xcode Apple Mach-O Linker error for CDVCamera

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm encountering an error during the build phase of my cordova (3.5) project:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource", referenced from:
  -[CDVCamera imagePickerControllerReturnImageResult] in CDVCamera.o
... and 15 more of those
```

A lot of posts noted, that i have to add the CDVCamera.m file into the compile sources section.
Without the entry i don't get the error... obviously my app won't be able to use the camera in that case.
I tried different versions of the plugin, but nothing changed.

Is there something i may have forgotten?

Comment: How did you add the plugin? The CLI should take care of all this for you automatically.

Comment: cordova plugin add .. and so on... yeah normally it should. all other plugins work perfectly. The camera plugin however, has some problems.... maybe i could set up a new project and check it out

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have had the same issue and I have managed to fix it from xcode:
Select Target
In `Build Phases` > `Link Binary With Libraries` you should add `ImageIO.framework` and `CoreGraphics.framework`

An image with my settings: http://screencast.com/t/rsxZrUkyslAY

Answer (score 0):

Following DotNetWise's advice I also had to add the Location framework to get it to work.